# How can I use a value as instance name in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to shorten these lines

```
var upgradethis = "u3";

if (nev == "u1"){
    mM.u1.count.text=minionCounter[lvl];
}
if (nev == "u2"){
    mM.u2.count.text=minionCounter[lvl];
}
```

How can I replace the "u1" and "u2" with value of "upgradethis"?

And use in here:

mM.**upgradethis's value**.count.text=minionCounter[lvl];

(replace the u2 in this code to value of "upgradethis")

Comment: Just try `mM[upgradethis].count.text`

Comment: @Cherniv Don't answer in comments, answer in answers.

Comment: @Cherniv, good job (see my previous comment btw).

Comment: @SlyRaskal thanks for the compliments!

Comment: @SlyRaskal Reputation is no indication of knowledge once you get past a certain limit. I believe I'm past that limit. Besides, if meta says one should post answers, not comments... Then maybe he's wrong? IMHO, Meta beats Rep any day of the week. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?rq=1):

Use `mM[upgradethis].count.text` to solve the issue.

Solution attributed to [Cherniv, who posted it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788479/how-can-i-use-a-value-as-instance-name-in-ac3#comment40333776_25788479).

Note that you can run into a `TypeError #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties` if you don't check if the property exists. You can use [`hasOwnProperty`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty()) (syntax `if(mm.hasOwnProperty(upgradethis))`) for this.

Comment: I would also suggest making sure the property exists when using dynamic property names, by adding `if mM.hasOwnProperty(upgradethis)`. It's good practice, even it you're pretty sure the property is there.